# How to extract specific data from HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to extract from HTML the following data: Date, Time, the first Jogo and, if the checkmark symbol is present on the first, second, third or fourth time or display 0 if there's no checkmark.

The returns fine all data when the checkmark is present, but when there's no checkmark it just displays the Date and Time.

My python code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="body">
   <div class="pull_right date details" title="09.03.2023 01:08:10 UTC-03:00">
      01:08
   </div>
   <div class="from_name">
         -  2.5 
   </div>
   <div class="text">
      Easy Bot - Over 2.5<br><br> Liga: Sul-Americana<br> Entrada: Over 2.5 FT<br>⚽ Jogos: ✅ 04:10 04:13 04:16 (04:19)<br><br><strong>Link: </strong><a href="https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B146/R%5E1/">https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B146/R%5E1/</a><br><br> 24h:100% de acerto nas últimas 24h<br><br>✅✅✅✅✅✅ .
   </div>
</div>
"""

# parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

d_str = soup.select_one('div.date.details')['title']
calendar = d_str.split(" ")
print("Date: ",calendar[0])
print("Time: ",calendar[1])
for sts in soup.select_one('div.text').stripped_strings:
    if "⚽ Jogos: " in sts:
        jugos = (sts.split('⚽ Jogos: ')[1].split(" "))
        ind = jugos.index('✅')+1
        jugos.remove("✅")
        print("Jogo 1: ", jugos[0])
        print("Checkmarked: ", ind)
```

Note that the checkmark "belongs" to the time. So it can be on the first, second, third or fourth Jogos time.

But sometimes there will be no checkmark. when this happens the output should be:

Date: XXX
Time: XXX
Jogo 1:  XXX
Checkmarked: 0

So, what's the problem with this code?

Comment: Something is unclear: you say "if the check mark symbol is present on the first, second, third or fourth time" - in your html you have one line of Jogos beginning with one check mark and 4 times (one in parentheses); does it mean the check mark "belongs" to the first time? I would suggest you edit your example to add another one with different check mark arrangement and, importantly, the exact expected output from the new example.

Comment: Yes the check mark is "attached" to the time marking it. I will edit the question with more details and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
d_str = soup.select_one('div.date.details')['title']
calendar = d_str.split(" ")
print("Date: ",calendar[0])
print("Time: ",calendar[1])
for sts in soup.select_one('div.text').stripped_strings:
    if "⚽ Jogos: " in sts:
        jugos = (sts.split('⚽ Jogos: ')[1].split(" "))
        if "✅" in jugos:
           ind = jugos.index('✅')+1
           print("Checkmarked: ", ind)
           jugos.remove("✅")
           print(jugos)
    else:
        print(jugos)
        print("Checkmarked: NA")
```

Output with check mark:

```
Date:  09.03.2023
Time:  01:08:10
['04:10', '04:13', '04:16', '(04:19)']
Checkmarked:  1
```

Output without check mark:

```
Date:  09.03.2023
Time:  01:08:10
['04:10', '04:13', '04:16', '(04:19)']
Checkmarked: NA
```

Of course, instead of printing you can add the output to a list, etc.

Comment: The code is fine, but when it faces Jogos that has no checkmark it displays only the date and time but not the Jogos times. I will update the question to add that.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida I don't get the same result as you, but I edit the question to account for no checkmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the expected result should look like or how many items are there to iterate, so this code should point into a direction.

---

Issue here is that `string='⚽ Jogos:'` needs an exact match.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="body">
   <div class="pull_right date details" title="09.03.2023 01:08:10 UTC-03:00">
      01:08
   </div>
   <div class="from_name">
         -  2.5 
   </div>
   <div class="text">
      Easy Bot - Over 2.5<br><br> Liga: Sul-Americana<br> Entrada: Over 2.5 FT<br>⚽ Jogos: ✅ 04:10 04:13 04:16 (04:19)<br><br><strong>Link: </strong><a href="https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B146/R%5E1/">https://www.bet365.com/#/AVR/B146/R%5E1/</a><br><br> 24h:100% de acerto nas últimas 24h<br><br>✅✅✅✅✅✅ .
   </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('.text'):    
    for s in e.stripped_strings:
        if 'Jogos' in s:
            s=s.split()[2:]
            jogo_times = [t for t in s if '✅' not in t]
            jogo_check = [s[i+1] for i,t in enumerate(s) if '✅' in t]
            d = {
                'date':e.find_previous('div',{'class':'date'}).get('title')[:10],
                'time':e.find_previous('div',{'class':'date'}).get_text(strip=True),
                'jogo_times':jogo_times,
                'jogo_time_checked':jogo_check
            }
            break
    if d:
        data.append(d)
        d = None   
    else:
        print('no jogo')
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'date': '09.03.2023',
  'time': '01:08',
  'jogo_times': ['04:10', '04:13', '04:16', '(04:19)'],
  'jogo_time_checked': ['04:10']}]
```

Comment: I got no output from your code.

Comment: In case you use the example exactly like this, the data should be printed directly from your environment, otherwise you would have to print it out. If you have adapted the code, it would need further details